# How do I hide a Font Awesome spinner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-awesome

I have the following spinner on an MVC .net Razor page:

```
 <div id="spinner1">Processing Video... <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw"></i></div>
```

It works fine. I have a Signal-R push to add data to the page (works fine). once the list of data is complete (works fine) I want to HIDE the sipnner.

I have tried:

```
$('#spinner1').display = 'none';
```

but nothing happens, the spinner still spins. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: you have to change the css("display") --> $('#spinner1').css("display", "none")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### jQuery

Assuming from the code in the question that you're using jQuery, jQuery objects don't have a `display` property. Instead, you'd use [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide):

```
$("#spinner1").hide();
```

...although you *could* use `display` directly, via the [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css) function or by accessing the raw DOM element from within the jQuery wrapper:

```
$("#spinner1").css("display", "none");      // Using `css`
$("#spinner1")[0].style.display = "none";   // Accessing raw DOM element
```

#### Not jQuery

Given that you've included the `#` in the `$("#spinner1")`, I think it's really unlikely, but: If you're using MooTools or PrototypeJS or something else that has a `$` function but returns a raw DOM element, the `display` property is on `style`:

```
// NOT JQUERY
$("spinner1").style.display = "none";
```

Note in those two cases, you don't include the `#` with `$()` (although you would with `$$()`).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, worked like a dream.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code:

```
<i id="spin" class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>
```

and in js:

```
$("#spin").hide();
```

It works fine for me.